# Showing that a map $T:V \to W$ with $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$ is not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $T:V\to W$ and $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$.

By the rank–nullity theorem, we know $\dim(V)=\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(T))+\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))$

So $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))<\dim(W)$ and therefore $T$ is not surjective.

Comment: Correct. What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, the dimension of a space must be a non-negative integer.  Your proof that $T:V \to W$ is not surjective is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it also without the rank-nullity theorem. Let $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ be a basis of $W$. If $f$ is surjective, then you can find $v_1,\dots,v_n$ such that $f(v_k)=w_k$ $(k=1,\dots,n)$. Since $n>\dim V$, you know that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly dependent, so also $\{f(v_1),\dots,f(v_n)\}$ is linearly dependent: contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

A short proof: $$\DeclareMathOperator\dim{dim}\dim(\operatorname{Im}T)\le \dim V<\dim W.$$